# How to package .scss files when publishing Storybook components in npm package?

Tags: reactjs, npm, storybook

I just published my Storybook components in an npm package (let's call it `my-storybook`) and followed this tutorial: https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/design-systems-for-developers/react/en/distribute/

but when I tried to use them in a project, I get the following error for each component exported in my package:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./node_modules/my-storybook/dist/stories/Button/Button.js 14:0-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './button.scss' in '/Users/storybook-test/my-app/node_modules/my-storybook/dist/stories/Button'
```

My Storybook component folder structure is like this:

```
/src
 /stories
   /Button
     Button.jsx
     button.scss
     Button.stories.jsx
```

As per the tutorial linked above, the build script for the publish is this:

```
"build": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=production babel src -d dist"
```

In my index.js, I export the components like so:

```
export * from "./stories/Button/Button";
```

When I went into the `dist` folder I saw that the .scss files were not being included with the export. I'm not sure if it's supposed to include them, but I don't know how to resolve this error. The `dist` folder tree looks like this:

```
/dist
 /stories
   /Button
     Button.js
     Button.stories.js
```

Both files in the `dist` folder have the line `require("./button.scss");` and that is the line that is giving me the error.

How can I resolve the error above when I try to import my components in a new React app? Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you kindly.

EDIT: Here is my `.storybook/main.js` file

```
module.exports = {
  stories: ["../src/**/*.stories.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app",
  ],
  framework: "@storybook/react",
  core: {
    builder: "@storybook/builder-webpack5",
  },
  staticDirs: ["../public"],
};
```

Comment: we need to see your webpack config. is there anything in there for loading sass?

Comment: @dqhendricks I will edit my question to include .storybook/main.js where you can customize the Webpack setup but I don't have any webpack config files in my project otherwise

Comment: default config doesn't mention sass support. this will show you how to add a sass loader to your storybook's webpack config (under extending storybooks webpack config): https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/builders/webpack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and I managed to solve it using rollup.js instead of webpack. Took me a little bit of time to get my head around it but it solved a lot of problems.

I like it because it transpiles the code (including scss) into single file cjs which makes it easier when importing.

This is the [documentation](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/) I used and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hf6Z8OZanec) was also helpful:

This is my **package.json file**:

```
{
  "name": "seb-storybook-test",
  "version": "1.0.13",
  "description": "just playing around",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.es.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook",
    "build-lib": "rollup -c --bundleConfigAsCjs"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "author": "Sebastian Meckovski",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.0.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack4": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack4": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.17",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "rollup": "^3.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^4.4.0",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-scss": "^3.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.1.0",
    "storybook-addon-sass-postcss": "^0.1.3"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

and this is the **rollup.config.js**:

```
import babel from "rollup-plugin-babel";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import external from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import scss from "rollup-plugin-scss";
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";

export default [
  {
    input: "./src/index",
    output: [
      {
        file: "dist/index.js",
        format: "cjs",
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      scss({
        insert: true,
      }),
      babel({
        exclude: "node_modules/**",
        presets: ["@babel/preset-react"],
      }),
      external(),
      resolve(),
      terser(),
    ],
  },
];
```

Hope this helps.

Edit 1:

Attaching my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/sebastian-meckovski/seb-storybook) so you can check detailed setup

Comment: Thank you for the help! Are your components in a .js or .jsx format? I think I'm having issues with it being in .jsx...

Comment: I don't think it matters. I do most of my components in .js but .jsx worked exactly the same, it never made any difference. There were some issues with declaring functions though. Components need to be set up like this **const component = () => {}** and imports need to be in curly braces like this **import {component} from './library.js'**

I've added a link to my GitHub repo so you can check the setup. You'll find some useful scripts in there for efficient publishing

Feel free to mark my question the best if it helps you

Comment: I ended up having to input this option in resolve: resolve({extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']} ) to get the .jsx to work. Thanks for your answer - it worked!